# Atom tsconfig not compiling (when it VScode it does)

Tags: typescript, compilation, atom-editor, tsc, tsconfig

I'm currently switching from VScode after some trouble with it.

My main problem is that in VScode my TypeScript compiles perfectly, but in Atom it is not doing anything ...

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "outFile": "application.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "files": [
    "app/application.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false,
    "formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

So when I do F6, it says `Building` then `Build success`, but I have no `application.js` in my webroot folder.

Structure looks like this :

```
-app
  -application.ts
  -someFolder
    -someComponent
      -someTs.ts
    -application.ts
  -someOtherFolder
    -someOtherComponent
      -someTs.ts
    -application.ts
```

So my `app/application.ts` have references inside that links to `someFolder/application.ts` and `someOtherFolder/application.ts` and both them have their references.

Any clues what is wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at the issues. It is a reported bug: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/883 Up for grabs by any hero.

Comment: I seached for about 2 hours with a lot of keywords and never found this ... wow ...

Thanks !

Comment: Note for future viewers, this was fixed by me in 8.3.1 : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/releases/tag/v8.3.1